# Link in footnote error from Calibre. Upload to d2D error

Tags: epub

Here is the error Draft2Digital is giving me when I upload my epub file:

ERROR(RSC-005): .tmp.tmpxl0rfcuu.epub/index_split_014.html(85,203): Error while parsing file: attribute "data-docx-vert" not allowed here; expected attribute "accesskey", "charset", "class", "coords", "dir", "href", "hreflang", "id", "lang", "rel", "rev", "shape", "style", "tabindex", "target", "title", "type" or "xml:lang"

Something about the format of the link seems to be off.  Here's the code for line 85:

```
<p class="block_6"> Jonathan Amos, “‘Case is Made’ for Anthropocene Epoch,” bbc.com, January 8, 2016, <a data-docx-vert="sup" href="http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-35259194" class="text_21">http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-35259194</a>.</p>
```

What's wrong with the link format, and how do I fix it?  Apologies for being a N00B

Comment: I deleted the "data-docx-vert="sup"" and it worked fine.  Any idea on what was causing calibre to dump that apparently unnecessary text in a bunch of links?

Comment: I solved the problem. Erasing number of a quote not mine, but from a source of a document I quoted.